# Calling rootProxy on NSConnections does not return

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, distributed-objects

I have two Cocoa-GUI-Applications (compiled with ARC, no sandboxing).

Application one has the following function:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    CommController *cc = [CommController new];
    NSConnection *theConnection;
    theConnection = [NSConnection new];
    [theConnection setRootObject:cc];
    if ([theConnection registerName:@"MyServer"] == NO) {
        /* Handle error. */
        NSLog(@"Could not start server.");
    }

}
```

And application two has the following function:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    id theProxy;
    NSConnection *theConnection;

    theConnection = [NSConnection
                     connectionWithRegisteredName:@"MyServer"
                     host:nil];
    theProxy = [theConnection rootProxy];
    [theProxy setProtocolForProxy:@protocol(NetProto)];

}
```

The call `[theConnection rootProxy]` from the second application never returns.
If I use the deprecated `[NSConnection defaultConnection]` instead of `[NSConnection new]` it works.
So I'm looking for a non deprecated way to get the rootProxy.

Comment: Does it help to do `[theConnection addRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]]` in the server?

Comment: Then `[theConnection rootProxy]` in the client returns `nil`...

Comment: Are you using ARC? Maybe `NSConnection` only holds a weak reference to the root object. What happens if you keep a strong reference to the `CommController` object in an instance variable?

Comment: Yes I'm using ARC. I now tried keeping a strong reference, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you also keeping a strong reference to the `NSConnection` object beyond the end of that method?

Comment: I do it now and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a strong reference to the `NSConnection` object as proposed by Ken Thomases helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
CommController *cc = [CommController new];
    NSConnection *theConnection;
    theConnection = [NSConnection new];
    [theConnection setRootObject:cc];
    if ([theConnection registerName:@"MyServer"] == NO) {
        /* Handle error. */
        NSLog(@"Could not start server.");
    }
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];//Start the current runloop
```

Comment: This helps somehow... The client can connect, but the servers GUI is not responsive any more.